# Unable to verify emails with JWT, need to find user with email but can't send email in the email

Tags: javascript, jwt, express-jwt

I am trying to verify user emails with JWT. My current set up is that a JWT is sent to a user when they try to log in if they do not have a confirmed email.

When the email is sent it composes a URL with the token and then sends the request to the server to verify the email. It worked great in postman as I could easily add the email that I want to verify in the body. But I can't think of a way how to do it in the browser.

This is the code that should verify the email.

```
    confirmEmail = async (req, res, next) => {

        const { email } = req.body
        const param = req.params.token

        const user = await userModel.findOne({email})

        if(!user)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'User not found')
        }

        if(user.confirmed)
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, 'User already confirmed')
        }

        if(!user.confirmed)
        {
            const confirmJWT = jwt.verify(param, process.env.SECRET_JWT)
            if(!confirmJWT)
            {
                throw new HttpException(200, 'Token invalid')
            }

            const result = await userModel.emailConfirmed(email)
        }

        res.send('Database updated.')

    }
```

This is the code that generates the JWT and sends it in an email.

```
        if(!user.confirmed)
        {
            const emailToken = jwt.sign(
                {
                    email: user.email
                },
                process.env.SECRET_JWT,
                {
                    expiresIn: '15m'
                }
            )
            
            console.log(emailToken)
            emailModel.verifyEmail(email, emailToken)
            throw new HttpException(401, 'Email not confirmed')
        }
```

I was wondering if there is any way I can use the just the token to find the email of the user or is that not possible with JWT?

```
export const verifyEmail = () => {
    try
    {
        return API()
        .post(`/api/confirm/:token`, {}, {
            params: {
                token: store.user.authToken
            },
            email: store.user.email
        })
        .then(({data: userData}) => {
            console.log('worked')
        })
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

```
import { verifyEmail } from '../../services/authAPI'
import { useUserStore } from '../../stores/user'

const store = useUserStore()

export default {
    data()
    {
        return {
            email: store.user.email
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async handleSubmit()
        {
            try
            {
                const response = await verifyEmail(this.email)
            }
            catch(err)
            {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried for the browser part?

Comment: Added, browser parts. Whilst searching I thought maybe I should redirect the link to the website instead of send them directly to server from the link in the email. That way I could pass an email that's been saved in the storage and link them with the JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do not need to send the email in the body as already encoded the email into the JWT. Once you do `const verifiedToken = jwt.sign(token, secret key)` You can do verifiedToken.email to grab the email.